# How to type a Class or Constructor

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, types, flowtype

I'm using a similar pattern to this:

```
class MyClass { }

doSomethingWithClass(MyClass) { }
```

If I were to add typing to my code, using Flow or TS, how would I type this? Wouldn't something like this imply that I'm expecting an instance of MyClass?

```
doSomethingWithClass(MyClass: MyClass) { }
```

What I want to do is pass the constructor/class into a factory pattern, but I don't know how to actually type it.

Comment: Do you want a generic factory pattern?

Comment: Essentially. I knew how to add a generic, but not how to type a constructor properly. @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir had the answer I was looking for. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

In order to pass a class constructor to a function you can use a constructor signature:

```
function doSomethingWithClassGeneric<T>(myClass: new () => T) { 
    return new myClass()
} 
doSomethingWithClassGeneric(MyClass);
```

Above we use a constructor with no arguments but you can potentially require parameters to the constructor to be present.

Or you can also use `typeof MyClass` to accept classes derived from `MyClass` with a compatible constructor:

```
class MyClass { }
class MyClassDerived extends MyClass  {  x!: number }

function doSomethingWithClassGeneric<T>(myClass: typeof MyClass) { 
    return new myClass()
} 
doSomethingWithClassGeneric(MyClass);
doSomethingWithClassGeneric(MyClassDerived);
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I need to spend some time in the docs. I'm removing this question. Cheers.

Comment: @Firephp not sure you should .. it might be useful to others

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Class<>](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-class) utility type.

```
class MyClass { };

function doSomethingWithClass(klass: Class<MyClass>): void {
}

doSomethingWithClass(MyClass)
```